# Logical proof for simple statement,

Tags: combinatorics, logic, recreational-mathematics, word-problem, ratio

This seems like a simple question... but I am struggling to find a conclusive proof.

(a) If Robinson's squash is double the strength of Johnson's squash, then you need to use double the volume of Johnson's squash as Robinson's squash for equivalent amount of drink.

(b) If you need to use double the volume of Johnson's squash as Robinson's squash for equivalent amount of drink, then Robinson's squash is double the strength of Johnson's squash.

I am almost certain that both statements (a) and (b) are valid, however I am struggling to prove it in mathematical terms.

How would you approach it?

Comment: You need to define the relationship between "strength", "volume", and "amount" of drink.

Comment: clearly not, if you are to claim that double the volume is the same amount as the stronger. $~$ Try, strength is amount per volume. $~~s(x):=a(x)\div v(x)$

Comment: @anon1234 By the way, you can see that continuing to hide your tracks elsewhere is **equally pointless**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A priori we need to define the relationship between "strength", "amount", and "volume".   Let $s(x), a(x), v(x)$ be the functions for these on some entity $x$ in the domain of discussion ($\mathcal S$, squashes).

Now, it seems reasonable that we should define strength as amount per volume.   Then our unstated axiom is: $\forall x{\in}\mathcal S~\big(s(x)=a(x)/v(x)\big)$

> If Robinson's squash is double the strength of Johnson's squash, then you need to use double the volume of Johnson's squash as Robinson's squash for equivalent amount of drink.

Well, let $j,r$ be the entities "Johnson's squash" and "Robinson's squash".

- $s(r)=2s(j)$ says "Robinson's squash is double the stength of Johnson's squash."
- $v(j)=2v(r)$ says "Johnson's squash is double the volumn of Robinson's squash."
- $a(j)=a(r)$ says "Johnson's squash is the same amount(of drink) as Robinson's squash."

Your task is *now* to use these predicates, and logical connectives, to express the claim as a nested conditional statement, then apply the definition to prove it.